# set size of clickable icon background

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to set the pressable area for a close icon. so if the icon is 19X19, the area to press will be 39X39. 
The div is the container of the clost botton, and i want to change it.
I don't want to set a fixed height, because it strach somtimes, in the other hand, there is no height at all to father, and his father...

```
<div class="ui-pnotify-closer" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Close"></span>
</div>
```

So I thought to do something like that:

```
.ui-pnotify-closer{
  margin: -10px -10px -10px 10px ;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

But this is very not elegant.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Looks elegant enough to me.. no extra markup and no Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something like below.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="test">
  <span><img src="test.gif" width="19" height="19" border="0" /></span>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .test
 {
  background-color:#ff00ff;
  padding:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline;
 }
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/pVc4r/)